# Get/Post web.php Create/Store Route Returns 404

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out why my create route returns a 404 error since it only gives me a **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)** on the page.

The show, edit, and update routes function with no issue and the views are located in the same folder as the create.blade.php file. My web.php appears to recognize the create function in the controller and the controller appears to recognize the create.blade.php file at least from vs code's Follow Link system. I've also tried emptying out the blade file and leave only a div, the extends and section but still receive a 404.

web.php

```
Route::get('/location/{location}', 'LocationController@show')->name('location.show');
Route::get('/location/create', 'LocationController@create');
Route::post('/location', 'LocationController@store');
Route::get('/location/{location}/edit', 'LocationController@edit')->name('location.edit');
Route::patch('/location/{location}', 'LocationController@update')->name('location.update');
```

Location.php

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Location extends Model
{

    public function casino() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Casino::class);
    }

    public function duties() {
        return $this->hasMany(Duty::class)->orderBy('title', 'ASC');
    }

}
```

LocationController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Location;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LocationController extends Controller
{
    public function create() {
        return view('locations.create');
    }

    public function store() {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
        ]);
        return redirect("/casino/" . location()->casino()->id);
    }

    public function edit(Location $location) {
        return view('locations.edit', compact('location'));
    }

    public function update( Request $request, Location $location) {

        $data = request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required'
        ]);

        $location->title = $request->get('title');
        $location->save();

        return redirect("/location/{$location->id}");
    }

    public function show(Location $location) {
        return view('locations.show', compact('location'));
    }

}
```

create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <form action="/location" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 offset-2">

                <div class="row pt-4">
                    <h1>Add New Location</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="title" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Location Title</label>
                    <input id="title"
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror"
                        name="title"
                        value="{{ old('title') }}"
                        required autocomplete="title"
                        autofocus>

                    @error('title')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror

                </div>

                <div class="row pt-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Add New Location</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Did you try to clear cache? `php artisan optimize`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your routes are in the wrong order.

Because your show route `/location/{location}` is at the top, it will catch `/location/create` and assume that `create` is the route parameter of a location that you are trying to view, therefore you never reach the `create` action but the `show` action instead.

Putting the `create` route above the `show` route should fix the problem:

```
Route::get('/location/create', 'LocationController@create');
Route::post('/location', 'LocationController@store');
Route::get('/location/{location}', 'LocationController@show')->name('location.show');
Route::get('/location/{location}/edit', 'LocationController@edit')->name('location.edit');
Route::patch('/location/{location}', 'LocationController@update')->name('location.update');
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn´t create an alias to your create route. Should be this?

```
Route::get('/location/create', 'LocationController@create')->name('location.create');
Route::post('/location', 'LocationController@store')->name('location.store');
```

Comment: From the tutorial I was following it did not seem like it was necessary, I don't think it's even necessary to use an alias for the other routes since I'm using the action name for the alias. Pulled out the aliases and everything still functions alright.